# Asymptote 3D viewable in Evince/Okular

Tags: 3d, asymptote, okular, evince

Is there a way to get Asymptote 3D figures in a PDF viewable in Evince/Okular?
All what I can get is a very bad rastered image in place of my figure.

I don't care about the interaction with the 3D figure.
I would be happy to get a clean vector graphics 2D projection (from a certain viewpoint) in a PDF file. My target is to include it in a LaTeX document that can be reliably opened with Evince/Okular.

- **Evince Version:** 2.28.2
- **Asymptote Version:** 2.16

I am trying the very basic 3D example of unit circle:

```
import three;
size(100);
path3 g=(1,0,0)..(0,1,0)..(-1,0,0)..(0,-1,0)..cycle;
draw(g);
draw(O--Z,red+dashed,Arrow3);
draw(((-1,-1,0)--(1,-1,0)--(1,1,0)--(-1,1,0)--cycle));
dot(g,red);
```

**Rastered Image:**

[image]
[image]

**3D view in Acroread**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several options to get `3d` `asy` viewable in other viewers than `Acrobat reader`
(without interactive `3d` feature). The options `-noprc` and `-render=<num>` have to be specified.
The command `asy -f pdf -noprc -render=0` results in `vector` output 
(there are some limitations, esp. when transparency is used to draw surfaces)
and the other way is, for example, `asy -f pdf -noprc -render=4` (or higher than `4`)
will generate a higher quality raster image.
This is a vector output viewed in Evince:
[image]

Versions used are:

- Evince Version: 3.2.1
- Asymptote Version: 2.24,

but it should work with your versions as well.

Comment: And how could we get both, a scalable vector graphics as the poster imgage *and* an interactive 3D model that opens on click on those Readers which support it?

Comment: @AlexG: It's a good question, never thought about it.
Not sure if these options are mutually exclusive.

Comment: `asy -f pdf -render=0` produces both, a preview as vector graphics *and* the PRC.